# What does a spell going "haywire" mean?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

Haywire Chance is described as

> "Haywire Chance affects how likely your spells are to trigger a highly
>   unstable resonance cascade event."

but what does it mean practically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your *Haywire Chance* stat is the chance you have of trigger a haywire effect when casting a spell, this is basically the spell equivalent of a critical hit.

However, **haywire is *broken* in version 1.0.3** and doesn't work as intended. We can see this from the [blog post](http://www.gaslampgames.com/blog/2011/07/21/laundry-day/#more-2165) describing the changes to be expected in 1.0.4:

> #### Bugs, Actual Bugs:
>
> - Haywire not triggering, except when it absolutely shouldn’t. (Vampirism, traps, everything but your spellcasting.)

Answer (score 2):

To be specific, Haywire does exactly one thing: it ignores enemy Magic Resistance (which at low levels is a huge effect in and of itself).  At one point it also doubled Magic Power for that spell, but that turned out to be too huge, so it was dropped. Ignoring Magic Resistance is plenty strong on the lower floors. :)

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, it is a magical critical hit. Spell effects are stronger, bigger, better. I can't really say how much it is, it seems to be unique for each spells.